# Sympy.real_roots выводит что-то не то

Tags: python

Пытаюсь решить уравнение методом sympy.real_roots(), при больших коэффициентах вместо списка корней на вывод получаю следующее:

```
[2*CRootOf(109*x**5 - 4157*x**4 + 50498*x**3 - 184552*x**2 - 527136*x + 3507840, 0), 2*CRootOf(109*x**5 - 4157*x**4 + 50498*x**3 - 184552*x**2 - 527136*x + 3507840, 1), 2*CRootOf(109*x**5 - 4157*x**4 + 50498*x**3 - 184552*x**2 - 527136*x + 3507840, 2), 2*CRootOf(109*x**5 - 4157*x**4 + 50498*x**3 - 184552*x**2 - 527136*x + 3507840, 3), 2*CRootOf(109*x**5 - 4157*x**4 + 50498*x**3 - 184552*x**2 - 527136*x + 3507840, 4)]
```

Как получить корни?

Код:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
roots = sp.real_roots(-109*x**5/3870720+4157*x**4/1935360-3607*x**3/69120+23069*x**2/60480+5491*x/2520+38-67, x)
print(roots)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
equation = -109*x**5/3870720+4157*x**4/1935360-3607*x**3/69120+23069*x**2/60480+5491*x/2520+38-67
roots = sp.real_roots(equation, x)
numeric_roots = [root.evalf() for root in roots]
print(numeric_roots)
```

Comment: спасибо, работает